# Testing POST request w/ Parameters to WCF Service

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I've created a WCF web service which is hosted locally through IIS. I've used the WCF test client to confirm that the service is working properly, and I am now wanting to test through a manual REST call. I'm using [RESTClient 3.1](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) to send the REST calls. I'm able to retrieve results from methods, but my attempts to send JSON in as parameters always results in null parameters. What am I doing wrong? The return body from my request is "FAIL :(" Thanks in advance! I've spent over a day on this problem so far.

**Service Contract:**

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
      Method = "POST",
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public string Route2(Position start)
    {
        if (start == null)
        {
            return "FAIL :(";
        }
        else
        {
            return "SUCCESS :)";
        }
    }
```

** web.config: **

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"/>
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="help" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="Primordial.GroundGuidance.Service.GroundGuidanceService">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Primordial.GroundGuidance.Service.GroundGuidanceService" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="web" contract="Primordial.GroundGuidance.Service.GroundGuidanceService"
      kind="webHttpEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="webEndpointWithHelp" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
     </services>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
         <standardEndpoint name="webEndpointWithHelp" helpEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Because I'm using RESTClient the call isn't just a string/file, but for header value pairs I have:
Accept: application/json
contentType: application/json

The body type is set to "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
body:

```
{
  "elevation": 0,
  "latitude": 35.31,
  "longitude": -116.41
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging at my problem for another day, it ended up being my JSON, not my use of WCF. I needed to specify the method parameter names in my JSON.  For my method

```
[WebInvoke(
      Method = "POST",
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public string Route2(Position start, Position end)
```

the appropriate JSON was:

```
{
    "start": {
        "elevation": 1,
        "latitude": 35.3,
        "longitude": -116.4
    },
    "end": {
        "elevation": 1,
        "latitude": 35.3,
        "longitude": -116.4
    }
}
```